# EPiServer find and consolidate duplicated Blocks

Tags: episerver, episerver-7

We have had a third party perform a content migration for us into EPiServer. Unfortunately the third party didn't quite grasp the concept of Blocks and instead of reusing blocks they have recreated the same block on many pages. I've been searching around to find a way of locating duplicate blocks that contain the exact same text and consolidating them into one shared block.

I'm wondering if anyone has done anything like this before? Will this have to be a manual task of going through all pages and looking for duplicated blocks?

I've been looking at the EPiServer database and tblContentProperty seems to hold the content I could search for but don't know how to isolate blocks specifically. Obviously if I could isolate these blocks i'd still need a way of updating the pages to use a single shared one.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards,

Daniel

Comment: I'd definitely suggest doing this through the API:s - manually editing the database can lead to a world of hurt. :)